# Switch case vs. Events: On game state update (UNITY, C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, switch-statement, state

Let's say that I have a *Unity* game with multiple managers `(Game, GUI, Sounds, Camera, Inputs, Terrain, ...)` instantiated through the *Singleton pattern*.

When the *GameManager* calls (or gets called) to change the game state `(Intro, Tutorial, Gameplay, ...)`, should it informs other managers of the new game state through **events** or rather handle it and perform specific action on each manager within a **switch case**?

Using *switch case*:

```
public static GameState currentGameState;
public static GameState previousGameState;

public void ChangeGameState(GameState newGameState)
{
    switch(state)
    {
    case GameState.Intro:
    //do stuff
    break;

    case GameState.Tutorial:
    //do stuff
    break;

    case GameState.Gameplay:
    //do stuff
    break;

    //and so on

    }

    previousGameState = currentGameState;
    currentGameState = newGameState;
}
```

Or using *events*:

```
public static GameState currentGameState;
public static GameState previousGameState;

public delegate void GameStateChanged(GameState prev, GameState curr, GameState new);
public static event GameStateChanged OnGameStateChanged;

public void ChangeGameState(GameState newGameState)
{
    OnGameStateChanged(previousGameState, currentGameState, newGameState);

    previousGameState = currentGameState;
    currentGameState = newGameState;
}
```

Which is the best practice/maintainable pattern here?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing. If you don't need other scrips to be notified when something happens, there is no need to use event here. If you need other scripts to be notified when something happens then go with events

Comment: Well either solution implies a notification, let's say I update the camera position on the _Gameplay_ state, I could do it within the case state or within a callback in my _CameraManager_ no? Sorry if I don't really get your answer :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is less preferable as it creates a hard dependency between your classes, it seems harmless but often leads interdependencies that are hard to break later on. Obviously you need to make the link somewhere, but GameManager having hardcoded mentions of classes dealing with sound or camera is a clear violation of separation of concern, the game manager should ideally not care about what other classes are doing, it's much better to have the cameraManager and soundManager subscribing to gameManager events - at the very least you are creating two points where one class references the other class, which is much better than creating one point where one class references two others - imagine later down the road where you have 10 managers, if you have a list of these somewhere in code it's not a great sign, as this will become more and more convoluted to manage down the road.

If you split it out you can encapsulate functionality related to stuff you want to do with the camera within a switch in camera script, and encapsulate sound functionality within another switch in the sound script. It sounds like duplicating code with the switch cases but those other switch cases will be much simpler than the main one that controls the state change graph, for example maybe you'll only play a sound when changing from state C to state D while you only move the camera in states A and C, try not to write code that overlaps few concerns.

While on the subject (I have spent considerable time thinking about various solutions, and there are good and bad sides to most approaches), here's my preferred way (this is personal preference:)

Consider that you still have to keep the variables around to know what the previous and next state was, because there might be other scripts that become awake later, and miss first x fires of the event, they need to be able to both subscribe to future state change events and know what the current and previous state was. That means that you still need the static vars, and this can be understood as not having a single source of truth. Lets say you make a mistake later on, where you forget to fire an event, or (as mentioned above) the target script is not yet subscribed to the event when you fire, and that script takes the state information from the variables, while other scripts take it based on their own state cache (as informed by delegate). This can lead to inconsistent states within your app (a certain module can think you are in a different state than others). It's not wrong just feels slightly dangerous.

The way I often solve this is to have a parameterless event (System.Action) that gets triggered when the state is changed (you can even tie those two so that the event gets fired automatically via the setter i.e.

```
    public static System.Action OnGameStateChange;
    protected static GameState _currentGameState;
    public static GameState previousGameState;
    public static GameState currentGameState
       { get { return _currentGameState;} 
         set { previousGameState=_currentGameState;
              _currentGameState=value;
              if (OnGameStateChange!=null) OnGameStateChange.Invoke(); } }
```

This way you always get the event if you change the field, but there's less of a risk of being in an inconsistent state (as in, same objects missing the update)
scripts can always safely reference the public field (it will be a single source of truth for that right value) and all listeners will be notified regardless of how you change the value. you could also make the setter protected so it cannot be called from outside your game manager class.

It's always best to have a little bit of self-distrust, assume you are an idiot and try to protect the code from yourself trying to mess it up six weeks from now because you might not fully remember which approach you decided to pick and why, it's best if the code guides you into writing new code in a consistent way.

Answer (score 1):

From what it sounds like about how your game is currently structured, I think it would be preferable to handle changes to the game state in `GameManager` (with a switch statement, for example) rather than informing the other managers of the new game state via events. This is because I don't think the other managers should be aware of what game state is. For example, let's say you want a change to the tutorial game state to involve actions with the camera and sound managers:

```
public void ChangeGameState(GameState newGameState)
{
    switch(state)
    {
    case GameState.Intro:
        //do stuff
        break;

    case GameState.Tutorial:
        cameraManager.MoveToTutorialPosition();
        soundManager.PlayTutorialAudio();
        break;

    case GameState.Gameplay:
        //do stuff
        break;
    }

    previousGameState = currentGameState;
    currentGameState = newGameState;
}
```

I think the above is preferable to communicating the game state changes via events to each of your other managers because each of your managers will then have to know how to handle each `GameState`. Compare to the other approach below:

```
public class CameraManager
{
    public void UpdateGameState(GameState gameState)
    {
        switch (gameState)
        {
            case GameState.Intro:
                // do stuff
                break;
            case GameState.Tutorial:
                MoveToTutorialPosition();
                break;
            case GameState.GamePlay:
                // do stuff
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class SoundManager
{
    public void UpdateGameState(GameState gameState)
    {
        switch (gameState)
        {
            case GameState.Intro:
                // do stuff
                break;
            case GameState.Tutorial:
                PlayTutorialAudio();
                break;
            case GameState.GamePlay:
                // do stuff
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you have a lot of logic in your `GameManager`, it might make sense to start refactoring to break down the class a bit more. For example:

- Instead of a switch statement, you can use the State design pattern to represent each switch case as its own class rather than using an enum value. (See [the chapter on the State pattern in Game Programming Patterns by Nystrom](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html) for more details.)
- While I've argued here that other managers aside from `GameManager` should not be aware of `GameState`, it may be appropriate for each manager to have its own states as well, depending on the manager's complexity. For example, a `CameraState` could be useful.

(I hope I've understood your question correctly. I'm not 100% sure on this, so I would love to hear other answers or feedback as well.)